# ADS Data in China?

Tags: here-api

I have an application that works nicely in the UK, using "https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json" for the routing, and "https://pde.api.here.com/1/index.json" for gathering the list of ADS tiles.

I also need it to work in China.  Using "https://route.hereapi.cn/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json" is the replacement for the routing URL, but there is no documentation for the equivalent ADS tile API?

Any URL's I have found don't return any results for the linkId's returned using routing.  I have appropriate app id's and codes for both UK and China.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fleet Telematics ADS isn't available in China yet. China only has very limited services for ADS now.